# Pass uiimage image url data to another view

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I have a collection view in main VC and need to pass image's url data to other VC

here is my code

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! EventAlbumCustom

            let release = arrayOfRels[indexPath.row]
            cell.pic.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: release.url))

            return cell
        }

        override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {


            let Dest  = segue.destinationViewController as! EventPhotoFullSize

            if (segue.identifier == "eventphotofullsize") {

                let cell = sender as! UICollectionViewCell
                Dest.imageURL = cell.pic .....??
            }               
        }
```

Cannot find cell's imageview `pic` and the url

Comment: Please share the rest of the code of your cell, etc. You're throwing the segue manually isn't? There are missing parts in your code

Comment: Segue created in storyboard and connected with collectionview cell to another view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot find the property declared in your cell because in the `prepareForSegue` you're casting the `sender` as `UICollectionViewCell` instead of the you've defined `EventAlbumCustom`, your code should like this instead:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

   let Dest  = segue.destinationViewController as! EventPhotoFullSize

   if (segue.identifier == "eventphotofullsize") {
      let cell = sender as! EventAlbumCustom
      Dest.imageURL = cell.pic
   }               
}
```

I hope this help you